# Not taking the log of a variable with lots of 0 observations

Tags: least-squares

I have some variables in an OLS that are very skewed to the right, so it could make sense to the log transformation of it, however there are lots of 0s in the variable, so that would mean I have to remove those, thus resulting in a loss of observations. Can I argue that I didn't want to take the log for this reason? (These are salaries, many have 0)

Comment: What's the problem with skewed variables?

Comment: A zero salary is not an actual salary at most jobs and probably represents "we didn't enter one," i.e., a missing value.  I would treat them as indicative of missing values rather than as actual zeros.  You can then log-transform the rest, however, as @Firebug hints, skewed variables aren't necessarily problematic.

Comment: @Firebug I thought normal distribution is preferred in OLS, but I might've been wrong then

Comment: @jbowman It's an observation of a training program where only part of the groups got money, so I could imagine 0 being a valid salary in this case

Comment: I'd probably create a categorical variable for "salary / not salary" in addition to the salary variable; the categorical variable will allow you to pick up any systematic differences between salaried and non-salaried people without biasing (or perhaps "reducing the effect on" would be better) the salary variable effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common to use $\log(1+x)$ in such a situation, so common that a collaborator or reviewer is likely to suggest doing so, yet this is problematic for a number of reasons.

1. There are no distribution assumptions on regression features, so there is not necessarily a requirement to transform at all.
2. A typical reason for taking the $\log$ of a variable is to make the interpretation in terms of percentages change. This is a legitimate reason to take a logarithm. However, when you take $\log(1+x)$, two issues get introduced. First, you are shoehorning a percent change from zero into such a framework. Second, you are changing the starting values of the nonzero elements. A claimed $5\%$ change does not have nearly the same meaning when the starting value is $1$ vs when it is $2$. Consequently, much of the desired “percent change” interpretation is lost. For an extreme example, consider how damaging adding one would be if all of y he $x$ values are less than one, and you go and double (triple, increase $100$-fold…) them.
3. If you just want to introduce nonlinear behavior, there are many other ways to do it, and taking the $\log(1+x)$ isn’t necessarily a good nonlinear feature. If you do it because it’s easy, your model performance might not be so great compared to other ways to introduce nonlinearity.
4. Why add $1?$ Why not add $0.1$ or $2$ or $\pi?$

I had to criticize such a $\log(1+x)$ feature yesterday, and if you don’t do it, someone is likely to say that you should, so you need to be prepared to offer a rebuttal.

My suggestion is to think hard about why you wanted to use a $\log$ transformation in the first place. Once you figure out why, you may want to ask an additional question (or several) on here asking how to proceed.

Finally, one of the comments remarks that zero salary isn’t a real salary at a job and probably indicates missing data. For the particular problem at hand, I find that quite reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried that, but then the distribution ends up being attrocious. There is a huge gap with 0 frequency between the values that were 0 and everything else. Could be a special case to this, since the variable is salary, so it's either 0 or in the thousands.

Comment: @JohnFire The rest of the post beyond the first line goes into why you might not want to use such a transformation, so winding up with an awful distribution after taking $\log(1+x)$ is kind of a lucky break in that you get a signal from the transformation that it doesn’t fix your problems.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess sometimes it has more pros than cons to do this, but personally I'm not a fan of it either overall